# Crear archivo .JAR en netBeans 11.3

Tags: java

Busqué por varios lados pero no encontré la forma de hacerlo. Me encuentro con vídeos/post que no me sirven, el caso, como creo un archivo .JAR en netBeans 11.3?

Me crucé distintos vídeos o post, y estan desactualizados ya que a mi no me salen las opciones que ellos ponen. Creo que cree el archivo pero no lo ejecuta. Esta en NetBeansProject > Proyecto > target

Por lo que vi nadie se le guarda ahí, se les genera dentro de una carpeta llamada "dist" y con un archivo de texto, cosa que no me pasa, no se si hice algo mal a la hora de crear el proyecto, o el paquete... además de que al darle doble clic ni me lo abre ¿saben que puede ser?

En la carpeta del proyecto solo me sale esto:

src
target
nbactions
pom

Comment: Ya intentaste hacer un clean and build? Ya sabes... de los botones grandotes con iconos que salen en medio.

Comment: Sí, fue la única forma de que me generara el .JAR pero no me lo abre.

Comment: qué no te lo abre? ya probaste correrlo con `java - jar larutadetujar/nombre de tu archivo.jar` ?? Como no sé tu sistema operativo esa sería la forma de correrlo en general.